# Options for restricting access to wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, security, htaccess

So i've installed a plug-in which allows me to enable two-factor authentication for my users. The problem is that to enable the plug-in i have to log in as that user and enable it via their profile page (wp-admin).

This isn't a problem except for the fact that there's nothing stopping the users from logging in and disabling the two factor authentication which is an issue.

I've looked around at a few issues and none have seemed to work, essentially i want restrict backend access to only a select few (myself and few others).

I've tried stealth login and a few some htaccess solutions and none have seemed to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it a mu-plugin ('Must Use' plugin). Any PHP file you put into /wp-content/mu-plugins/ will automatically get included in WordPress. You can't deactivate the plugin (unless you have ftp access to the server). If you go with a mu-plugin, make sure to put the functionality into a subdirectory and bootstrap it with a php file in the mu-plugins directory.

### EDIT

After reading the comment, I think I understand the problem better. It sounds like you want to be able to lock people out of the admin altogether. That's not so difficult. Try this:

```
function my_awesome_admin_lockout(){
  if( is_admin() && !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    die();
  }
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_awesome_admin_lockout' );
```

Basically, that locks everybody but admins out of the admin area.

Comment: It's not so much disabling the plugin, they can log in and configure it in a way which disables it. So i can enforce the activation of the plugin but i don't want them to change the options of the plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

How about you revoke mysql write permissions on the table of the plugin

Anyone who would want to modify any value , will get an error.

If you want to update - you have to change permissions back,update the records,deny permissions again.

Answer (score 0):

I havn't tried it. But it may work for you.

1. Restrict complete access to wp-admin
   using .htaccess.
2. Now Make an alias php file outside
   of wp-admin or in some other folder.
3. Include wp-admin.php or necessary
   php file into alias PHP file.
4. restrict search engines to look into
   folder which contains your alias
   file using [robots.txt](http://article-stack.com/education/web-design-n-development/blog-blogger-blogging/why-does-robots-txt-is-important.amty)