# Change WP-Login or WP-Admin

Tags: wp-admin, admin, login, security, hacked

Can I change the name of the wp-login or wp-admin file so that I can go to a different filename in order to login. I am trying to prevent hackers from finding my login and wp-login has become a very obvious option.

Comment: Please see as well: [Options for restricting access to wp-admin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/options-for-restricting-access-to-wp-admin), [Can I rename the wp-admin folder?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106/can-i-rename-the-wp-admin-folder/126) and [How to change “wp-admin” to something else without search-replacing the core?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20240/how-to-change-wp-admin-to-something-else-without-search-replacing-the-core)

Comment: The simple fact of knowing where your login link is should not be a security vulnerability (otherwise you are probably in trouble in any case). If you are worried you should look into more protection fofr login (like SSL) and not just trying to hide it.

Comment: Try this, it works on my site: http://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-wp-login/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know you cannot rename wp-admin. Many themes and plugin uses wp-admin in path. So if you rename it then all your plugins and themes will be broken. If you don't want your users to access wp-admin then restrict it using .htacess If anyone access your wp-admin url redirect them to other page using .htaccess file. Only allow certain IPs to access wp-admin.

For example use this .htaccess code in your root of wp-admin (Not your wordpress root).
Create a new .htaccess file there and use this code.

```
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Example Access Control"
AuthType Basic
<LIMIT GET>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
allow from xx.xx.xxx.xx
</LIMIT>
```

Replace xx.xx.xx.xx with your IP address. You can add more. Thereafter only you can access wp-admin. You can also use [redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/screenshots/) plugin.

If you must want to rename wp-admin then proceed to read more but with extreme caution.

Just replace "wp-admin" with your keyword. Use this [simple search and replace](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/search/) tool.
Here is the [screenshot](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/search/screenshots.shtml) of that tool.

**Warning: If you update your wordpress then your site will be broken. You should replace them in themes and plugins too. I highly *NOT* recommend this option. Use this option only if its mandatory. I'm not responsible for any problem that arises if you use this option.**

Comment: @php-monkey I checked your tutorial. I think you are wasting your time in editing everything with notepad. Just use simple [search and replace tool](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/search/). It scans all your directory files and replace all the texts within minutes. Its a 1 or 2 minute work. But i believe you wasted so much time in editing each files. Sorry i couldn't add comment in your answer

Comment: You have flagged to remove community wiki status from your answer, but this doesn't seem to be possible.